# I try to Post a json Object to get the Authentication token in C#

Tags: c#, json, httpresponse

I try to Post a json Object to get the Authentication token in C#.
I´m new to this and I try to work myself into it but I´m getting an Exception (The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed
unexpectedly)
I have an API with the documentation [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojp3l.jpg)

and this code:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://URL/api/authenticate/authenticate");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = "{\"applicatoinKey\":\"MYAPPLICATIONKEY\"," +
                    "\"userSecret\":\"MYUSERSECRET\"}";

    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

And I have no idea where I made a mistake.

Comment: You don't need `streamWriter.Close();` when using a `Using` statement.

Comment: At which point of the code, the exception occurs?

Comment: @DanielShillcock ok but still the same error

Comment: @Smartis here:  var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

Comment: try adding httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

Comment: @Nirman thanks but still the same error

Comment: @Friedlman From my POV this code is absolute valid. Did you check the API with another Tool like `Postman` https://www.getpostman.com/ ?

Comment: @Smartis Thank you I did now. It gives me a 500 Internal Server Error Cause: Unable to execute the REST operation

Comment: @Friedlman Could it be, that the API isn't working at all?

Comment: @Smartis Always the same error. I have now tried to conntact the creator of the api. I will let you know his response. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Smartis Now it works with Postman but still the same error with my code... I even copied the Restsharp code from Postman but it gives me an emtpy response. Cant find the error

Comment: Try adding "System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;" before you call the GetResponse() method: